# Require is not defined in mdx

Tags: reactjs, vite, storybook

I'm running latest storybook 7 on vite. I have a simpel MDX. But I get an error:

require is not defined
ReferenceError: require is not defined
at http://localhost:6006/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js?v=e0a9ac34:6:3

```
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';

<Meta title="Hello World" parameters={{ docs: { page: null } }} />

# Hello, World!

This is a simple example of an MDX file in Storybook.

<Story name="Default">
  {() => <div>Hello, World!</div>}
</Story>
```